# Hiding a link from anonymous users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, authorization, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm using only `devise` gem for the user authorisation.

```
  <ul class="actions">
    <li>
      <%= link_to 'New Item', new_item_path, class: 'new' %>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

How can I hide the New Item link from anonymous users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`user_signed_in?` is predefined method provided by devise to check if user logged in or not.

```
<ul class="actions">
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <li>
      <%= link_to 'New Item', new_item_path, class: 'new' %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```